# How can I enable access to a folder/page only from two IP address using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder called `admin` in my root directory. Is there any way I can block all access to that folder from web but have open to two IP addresses?

I have seen this in Stack Overflow before

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

bus first of all this is only for one IP and also how I can just bind the `admin` folder here and not all other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the .htaccess file in the folder you want to protect. Add multiple lines for each IP-address you want to allow.

```js
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <first ip>
allow from <second ip>
allow from <third ip>
```

As an alternative, you can add this to your .htaccess file in the root.

```js
<Directory "/path/to/admin">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
allow from <first ip>
allow from <second ip>
allow from <third ip>
</Directory>
```